# How does OSMBuilding add 3D model?

Tags: openstreetmap

I was wondering how [F4](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/F4_Map) added the eiffel tower model on top of the OSMBuilding?

I want to add 3D buildings for my city.

http://demo.f4map.com/#lat=48.8591098&lon=2.2945308&zoom=18&camera.theta=50

Answer (score 2):

[F4 map](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/F4_Map) is a proprietary project by [F4 Group](http://www.f4-group.com). It shows a basic OSM map with various [*simple 3D buildings*](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_3D_buildings) that are part of the OSM database. Apart from these simple buildings it has been enhanced with a few more complex buildings such as the Eiffel tower. These more complex buildings are *not* part of OSM. You have to get in contact with F4 Group about adding similar buildings for your city. However you can check if the *simple 3D buildings* scheme is sufficient for you. In that case you can add your buildings right into the OSM database.